# Is there a pure-CSS way to highlight a html table column on hover?

Tags: html, css, hover, html-table

Is there a pure-CSS way to highlight a html table column on hover?

So when you hover over on `<td>`, all of the other `<td>` of that same child position would take on the same style?

I looked at `<col>` tag, but didn't seem to do what I expected.

Comment: I could, but that seems like the wrong way to go about it. Especially as I want it to do all of the columns, whichever is hovered over. And the table could be of any number of columns.

Comment: you can do this with javascript for sure, but I don't know css...

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/simple-css-row-column-highlighting/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like what you want is done by [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/simple-css-row-column-highlighting/)

Basically you just set a crazy high height on the TDs on hover and then give a background. Seems to be a pretty interesting thought to do this. They love their hacks. The `table{ overflow: hidden; }` is super key here.

WORTH NOTING.... Can't do nested with this approach.

> The negative z-index keeps it below the content. Negative z-index is a
>   fun trick, but beware this table then can't be nested within other
>   elements with backgrounds, otherwise the highlight will go below them.

Comment: Nice, works well, thanks. A little trouble with bootstrap striped columns which I'll need to work through, but certainly does work, and without any Javascript (unless you're doing mobile).

Answer (score 1):

With the latest selector [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) we can do something like following:

```css
:root {
  --on: aqua;
  --off: transparent;
}

table {
  --hover: var(--off);
}

table:has(td:nth-child(1):hover) td:nth-child(1) {
  --hover: var(--on);
}

table:has(td:nth-child(2):hover) td:nth-child(2) {
  --hover: var(--on);
}

table:has(td:nth-child(3):hover) td:nth-child(3) {
  --hover: var(--on);
}

table:has(td:nth-child(4):hover) td:nth-child(4) {
  --hover: var(--on);
}

td {
  background-color: var(--hover);
}

tr:has(:not(th)):hover {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><th>One</th><th>Two</th><th>Three</th><th>Four</th></tr>
    <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td><td>four</td></tr>
    <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td><td>four</td></tr>
    <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td><td>four</td></tr>
    <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td><td>four</td></tr>
    <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td><td>four</td></tr>
    <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td><td>four</td></tr>
</table>
```

**Note:** This works only when the number of columns is fixed.
Till Firefox supports the tag try this in Chrome.